# 其之 what's the exact meaning of this?

Tags: meaning, archaic-language, kosoado

I'm translating a comic and I found this kanji combination on the headers. It's like a counter for pages.

> 其之一
>   其之二
>   etc.

その is the reading. I wanted to get more info about that but I didn't find anything via google. Is that somehow familiar to you or is this way how it's written just really old?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

其之 is a rare kanji version of その meaning "its". The kanji 其 on its own means "it" and 之 means "～'s". Today その is almost always written in kana, but they used difficult kanji for archaism. Is the comic about ninja or something?

その is usually used as an old counter-like prefix for chapters/episodes/parts of a story, not pages. For example その5 typically means "episode 5" or "part 5", not "page 5".

Comment: the comic is a doujin about dragon ball.
thank u for the information I was not sure if the typical sono was the same as this kanji combination.

Comment: @lovelykotori That makes sense, Dragon Ball was loosely based on an old Chinese novel.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Dragon Ball is based loosely on Journey to the West. More information can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West

Comment: I think その works like the number sign (#). E.g. その１("#1"), その２("#2"), その３("#3") and so forth. Or like this: ルールその１、ルールその２、ルールその３...("Rule #1, Rule #2, Rule #3"...)

Comment: 此れ（これ）、其れ（それ）、何れ（どれ）、are still used occasionally in literary materials, restaurant and product names, etc. （also 此の and其の).  The possessive particle 之 （の）can also be seen fairly often in surnames, given names, and some other instances.

Answer (score 1):

The normal meaning was explained clearly by previous people, as a Chinese learning Japanese I want to say some other things.

其:
Chinese: it's(Third person possessive pronoun)
Japanese: it(Third person personal pronoun)

X 之 Y:
Chinese: Y of/in/etc X, X's Y ~= 的(Modern)
Japanese: mainly X's Y, == の

We Chinese only use "其一"(Chi' i in Mandarin, Ki' iat in Cantonese) to explain the same meaning as Japanese "其之一"(その一, sono ichi)

Back to the topic, Japanese "其之一" means first of something, something might be a actual topic/person/thing or others. We Chinese & Japanese & Korean usually use Third person pronoun to represent the current topic.